# Better way to query GPS regularly

Tags: android, gps

I have a timer that runs every second. Every second I get the GPS location and do other stuffs.
I am wondering which way is better:

1- Request a single location update and then get the last known location

```
private void timeout(){
        String data[] =new String[DATA_LENGTH];
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);

        Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
.
.
.
}
```

2- Start Location listener and then just get the last known location whenever my timer expire

```
OnCreate(){
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}
private void timeout(){
            String data[] =new String[DATA_LENGTH];


            Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Thank you

PS: Note that battery is not a concern to me as per the requirement of the product

Comment: Do you need to do these `other stuff` even if the location hasn't changed?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. No matter what I need to do the other stuffs every second even if the location is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestSingleUpdate` is meant to be single, if you need to query the GPS frequently you should definitely go with option 2.

Keep a global `Location` object in memory, use it in you *other stuff* and update it whenever your listener gets an update from the LocationManager.

Comment: Ok assuming I go with second approach, do I need the location variable in memory? Wouldn't grtLastKnown location will get me the last location gps acquired?

Comment: Yes, it will. I'm just not sure how expensive its implementation is. But if you do not run into performance issues, getLastKnownLocation is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for changes via `requestLocationUpdates` - the code below is a quick-n-dirty example (untested).  Remember, you have to have location services turned on to use this.

```
LocationListener locGPSListener= new LocationListener() {...}
LocationListener locNetworkListener= new LocationListener() {...}

mgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
// listens using GPS for location
mgr .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locGPSListener);
// uses towers for location
mgr .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locNetworkListener);
...
```

Comment: I have this code in my question. I don't want to act based on changes to location. I want to act every second. I need to know which way of above is better

Answer (score 0):

What approach is better, depends on

1. Androids GPS behaviour and
2. your Application.

ad 1. if explicitly getting a location delivers a more recent fix, than this is an advantage, because:

ad 2. if your application don't want the android filtering behaviour, and you can filter it yourself better, then this would be better for your app.

Example: (is for ios, but may apply here too:) if I drive  with my car to a traffic signal, and do a harsh breaking, then ios still shows 5 km/h speed, although I am standing still. This I call unwanted filtering.

This has all nothing to do with battery: if you get the location via message or if you query it is the same from battery point of view. It smore a software design issue: (events vs. polling)
A difference would only be if GPS is disabled, but disabling GPS makes only sense if it can be disabled for long time.

Comment: Not sure why I am not able to follow your answer. What does ad mean?

Comment: ad is the latin abbrevation for "addendum" , and means "to topic x I want to add the following info":